# filter data by values (common values but different data entry) stored in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on the data below how can I filter data by values stored in another dataframe object?

Sample data:

```
# Data to be filtered
Dest_FIPS = c(1,2,3,4)
Dest_county = c("West Palm Beach County","Brevard County","Bay County","Miami-Dade County")
Dest_State = c("FL", "FL", "FL", "FL")
OutFlow = c(111, 222, 333, 444)
Orig_county = c("Broward County", "Broward County", "Broward County", "Broward County")
Orig_FIPS = c(5,5,5,5)
Orig_State = c("FL", "FL", "FL", "FL") 

df = data.frame(Dest_FIPS, Dest_county, Dest_State, OutFlow, Orig_county, Orig_FIPS, Orig_State)

# rows to be filtered in column Dest_county based on the values in val_df 
COUNTY_NAM = c("WEST PALM BEACH","BAY","MIAMI-DADE") #(values are actually stored in a CSV, so will be imported as a dataframe)
val_df = data.frame(COUNTY_NAM) # will use val_df to filter df
```

Desired output:

```
Dest_FIPS Dest_county               OutFlow Orig_county
1         West Palm Beach County    111     Broward County
3         Bay County                333     Broward County
4         Miami-Dade County         444     Broward County
```

Comment: Several of the objects named in `df` do not exist.

Comment: They do but with different data entry like `West Palm Beach County` is entered as ` WEST PALM BEACH`  in the other dataset.

Comment: your call to `data.frame` includes vectors `FIPS`, `county`, and `State`, did you mean `Origin_FIPS`, `Dest_county`, and `Dest_State`? Also, you misspelled `Orig_county`

Comment: Oh right, thank you for pointing that out, it has been fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform `df$Dest_county` to match the format in `val_df`, then check which values are `%in% val_df$COUNTY_NAM`.

Base R:

```
df[toupper(gsub(" County", "", df$Dest_county)) %in% val_df$COUNTY_NAM,]
```

tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)

filter(df, str_to_upper(str_remove(Dest_county, " County")) %in% val_df$COUNTY_NAM)
```

Output for both:

```
    Dest_FIPS            Dest_county Dest_State OutFlow    Orig_county Orig_FIPS Orig_State
1           1 West Palm Beach County         FL     111 Broward County         5         FL
2           3             Bay County         FL     333 Broward County         5         FL
3           4      Miami-Dade County         FL     444 Broward County         5         FL
```